# PowerShell generalise data from csv column name

Tags: powershell

I'm importing data from CSV across multiple servers using the same script. Between each server, the column name within the CSV can change.

Is there a way where I can "generalise" the variable so the script will use either "aaa", "aba", "aca" or "ada" / a known set of variations per variable?

Right now I'm updating the scripts manually on each server with the correct column name to use e.g. $_.'data1', the end goal is to generalise the script.

Comment: Can you show us some of these csv files? Is it just one column name that needs generalising or are there more? Should the csv be rewritten on the servers with the new column name(s) ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generalise the reading of a csv file with possibly unknown field names (column names).  I did this in a little tool I wrote called Expand-csv.  What this tool does is import a csv file and loop through the records (rows) and for each record generate an expansion of a template, where the template contains powershell variables with the same column names as the csv file.

In order to make the tool more generic, I loop through the column names inside the outer loop,  defining a variable whose name is derived from the column name.

This solves a problem that's more generic than you are looking for,  but I am including the tool so you can see how the inner loop works, and maybe adapt the technique for your case.

```
 <#
.NOTES
    Script: Expand-Csv    Rev:  3.2
    By:     DGC           Date: 2-21-19
.SYNOPSIS
    Generates multiple expansions of a template,
    driven by data in a CSV file.
.DESCRIPTION
    This function is a table driven template tool. 

    It generates output from a template and
    a driver table.  The template file contains plain
    text and embedded variables.  The driver table 
    (in a csv file) has one column for each variable, 
    and one row for each expansion to be generated.
#>
function Expand-csv {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $driver,
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $template
    )
    Process {
       Import-Csv $driver | % {
           $_.psobject.properties | % {Set-variable -name $_.name -value $_.value}
           Get-Content $template | % {$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)} 
       }
    }
}
```

I am also including a file that shows a couple of demo runs to the tool for the sake of future visitors.

```
    
    Example 1:  Template
    --------------------
    

grant $privs 
   on $table 
   to $user;

    
    Example 1:  CSV File
    --------------------
    
privs,table,user
ALL,Employees,DBA
READ,Employees,Analyst
"READ, WRITE", Employees, Application
ALL,Departments,DBA
READ,Departments,"Analyst, Application"
    
    Example 1:  Driver
    ------------------
    

privs       table       user                
-----       -----       ----                
ALL         Employees   DBA                 
READ        Employees   Analyst             
READ, WRITE Employees   Application         
ALL         Departments DBA                 
READ        Departments Analyst, Application


    
    Example 1:  Results
    -------------------

grant ALL 
   on Employees 
   to DBA;


grant READ 
   on Employees 
   to Analyst;


grant READ, WRITE 
   on Employees 
   to Application;


grant ALL 
   on Departments 
   to DBA;


grant READ 
   on Departments 
   to Analyst, Application;

    
    Example 2:  Template
    --------------------
    
& java -jar --create -user $name -id $id -file D:/HR/$name-$id-form.pdf
   
    Example 2:  CSV File
    --------------------
    
NAME,ID
John,18
Dave,19
Carmen,20
Eric,21
Tom,22
Lisa,23
Kyle,24
   
    Example 2:  Driver
    ------------------
    

NAME   ID
----   --
John   18
Dave   19
Carmen 20
Eric   21
Tom    22
Lisa   23
Kyle   24


    
    Example 2:  Results
    -------------------
& java -jar --create -user John -id 18 -file D:/HR/John-18-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Dave -id 19 -file D:/HR/Dave-19-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Carmen -id 20 -file D:/HR/Carmen-20-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Eric -id 21 -file D:/HR/Eric-21-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Tom -id 22 -file D:/HR/Tom-22-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Lisa -id 23 -file D:/HR/Lisa-23-form.pdf
& java -jar --create -user Kyle -id 24 -file D:/HR/Kyle-24-form.pdf
```